# pythonic way to count the number of times words from a list / set occur in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, find-occurrences

Given a list / set of labels

```
labels = {'rectangle', 'square', 'triangle', 'cube'}
```

and a dataframe df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['rectangle rectangle in my square cube', 'triangle circle not here', 'nothing here'], columns=['text'])
```

I want to know how many times each word in my set of labels occurred in the text column of the dataframe and create a new column which has the top X (maybe 2 or 3) most repeated words. If 2 words are repeated equally as much then they can appear in a list or string

Output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'text' : ['rectangle rectangle in my square cube', 'triangle circle not here', 'nothing here'], 'best_labels' : [{'rectangle' : 2, 'square' : 1, 'cube' : 1}, {'triangle' : 1, 'circle' : 1}, np.nan]})                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                      
df['best_labels'] = some_function(df.text)
```

Comment: Is `pd.DataFrame({'text' : ['rectangle rectangle in my square cube', 'triangle circle not here', 'nothing here'], 'best_labels' : [{'rectangle' : 2, 'square' : 1, 'cube' : 1}, {'triangle' : 1, 'circle' : 1}, np.nan]})` something you have, or is that part of the expected output?

Comment: Why not just leave an empty set in `best_labels` for the case where nothing matches? `np.nan` ("not a number") is a strange "default" value to use here, since *none of the valid values are numbers either*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

labels = {'rectangle', 'square', 'triangle', 'cube'}    
df = pd.DataFrame(['rectangle rectangle in my square cube', 'triangle circle not here', 'nothing here'], columns=['text'])
    
df['best_labels'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: {k: v for k, v in Counter(x.split()).items() if k in labels} or np.nan)    
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                    text                               best_labels
0  rectangle rectangle in my square cube  {'rectangle': 2, 'square': 1, 'cube': 1}
1               triangle circle not here                           {'triangle': 1}
2                           nothing here                                       NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to visualize your data is with a matrix:

```
(df['text'].str.extractall(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(labels)))
           .groupby(level=0)[0]
           .value_counts()
           .unstack()
           .reindex(df.index)
           .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

   cube  rectangle  square  triangle
0   1.0        2.0     1.0       NaN
1   NaN        NaN     NaN       1.0
2   NaN        NaN     NaN       NaN
```

The idea is to extract text from rows which are specified in `labels`, then find how many times they occur per sentence.

What does this look like? Yup, you guessed it, a sparse matrix.